# Center Alignment Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a div element with a class name `row`, and it contains 2 div elements with these bootstrap class properties: `col-lg-3` and `col-lg-5 ml-auto`. After decreasing, the screen "col-lg-5 ml-auto" goes to another line. I want to center this element which is already on line 2. My question is: why does `justify-content: center` not work but `text-align: center` does?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
                <div class="nav d-flex">
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Features</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Support</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
                <div class="nav d-flex">
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Features</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Support</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the class to include `d-flex justify-content-center`.
It would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
                <div class="nav d-flex">
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Features</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Support</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Refer to the bootstrap documentation on flexbox containers here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/